# Create a login with two ASYMMETRIC KEYs

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, wcf

I'm working with SQL SERVER 2012 SP1 Express edition.

I want to add two assemblies to my database because I'm creating a Stored Procedure to access a WCF SOAP service. I'm following this [tutorial](http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com.es/2014/02/calling-wcf-service-from-stored.html) to do it.

On that tutorial says that I have to do this:

```
alter database [MyDemoDB]
set trustworthy on;
go
```

But I don't want to use `set trustworthy on;`. So, following this another [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2011/10/29/deploying-sql-clr-assembly-using-asymmetric-key.aspx) I have to create a login from asymmetric key.

The problem is that I have two assemblies, and I don't know how to create a login with two `ASYMMETRIC KEY`s or if it is necessary.

Now I have this SQL:

```
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY CodeServerDBKey FROM EXECUTABLE FILE = 'D:\CodeServerDB.dll'
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY CodeServerWCFClientKey FROM EXECUTABLE FILE = 'D:\CodeServerWCFClient.dll'
CREATE LOGIN SQLCLRTestLogin FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY CodeServerDBKey, CodeServerWCFClientKey
GRANT EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY TO SQLCLRTestLogin
```

Do I need to create the login with both Asymmetric keys?

BTW, `CREATE LOGIN SQLCLRTestLogin FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY CodeServerDBKey, CodeServerWCFClientKey` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create *two* logins and grant external access to each. But are you sure both assemblies required external access? Only the one actually using the privilege should be granted.

Asside from that, accessing HTTP from SQLCLR is a really bad idea. Make your slow, blocking, unreliable calls from your client app, do no hijack precious server workers to wait on the intertubez. If you decide to ignore this, at least make sure you read about [quantum punishment](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlclr/archive/2006/04/14/576716.aspx) and properly call [`Thread.BeginThreadAffinity()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.beginthreadaffinity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) before placing the HTTP request.

Comment: Great. I'm not going to access HTTP from SQLCLR.